# Wordpress occur an error when goes to edit page

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, plugins

I have create a wordpress plugin and recently it create a issue with page builders.

When my plugin is active then I found this issue arise in a page where used short code for a front end. the exception message is "**The editor has encountered an unexpected error.**"

And in console I checked an error found like below:

Error: Minified React error #31; visit [https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Brendered%7D&args[]=](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args%5B%5D=object%20with%20keys%20%7Brendered%7D&args%5B%5D=) for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

I also attach a snap of raised issue.

[image]

I have searching many solutions but could not get desired one. I just linked js/css only my plugin page. In somewhere I found that some are suggest for use classic editor instead of block editor or page builder. but I need to use page builder.

Comment: I am having this same problem. In my care - I have not found a solution, but found some clues. I found that - if you are able to either close the "settings" panel, or get into view -> preferences -> panels and then deselect "Page Attributes" the error will no longer happen.